# Modifying a views organic groups exposed filter

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have a view with an exposed filter of organic group id's (ie: gid). I wanted to convert it to be a dropdown with the actual group name. I did so with a form alter. The filter works fine, however I'm having an issue with the filter when trying to view all groups. I tried adding 'ALL' to the dropdown, but that doesn't match a particular gid, so it doesn't work. How can I fix my code to allow content of all groups to show?

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function tma_views_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] === 'views-exposed-form-event-list-page') {
    $form['field_event_type_tid']['#type'] = 'hidden';
  }
  elseif ($form['#id'] === 'views-exposed-form-page-event-calendar-page') {
    $form['og_group_ref_target_id'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => tma_views_get_chapters_list(),
      '#default_value' => 'ALL',
    );
  } 
}

/*
 * Retrieves an associated array list of all Chapter nodes
 * return - a list of nids
 */
function tma_views_get_chapters_list() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'chapter');
  $results = $query->execute();
  foreach ($results['node'] as $node) {
    $nids[] = $node->nid;
  }
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  $options['ALL'] = 'Select Chapter';
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $options[$node->nid] = $node->title;
  }
  return $options;
}
```

EDIT: 
One more thing to note: when no filter is set at all (for the organic group filter), I get a drupal error message on the screen:

```
An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

I obviously would like to be able to fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you would want to modify that filter in the Views UI. Is **required** checked? Also, a standard practice that I've seen for Drupal select is having all actually keyed with **_none** rather than **ALL**.

Comment: Actually part of the problem is (I forgot about this) is that the Organic Group filter doesn't come with a select list widget option in the first place. It only comes with a input box. This is why I needed the form_alter to turn it into a select this, which causes the issue I am describing. I tried setting it to _none, and setting it as required, but that didn't help. Any other ideas?